# How to get keys of Resource object in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS and have some problems with Resource object that is returned by $resource. If I call `data['something']`, I get what I want. But the problem is that I don't know key and Resource has no `.keys()` function. How can I solve this? Resource object has only one key, if this helps.

Factory for request:

```
.factory('StorageRequest', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/storage/:id/query/:queriString', {id: '@id'}, {});
    }
]);
```

Code:

```
query = "ABC_12345";
StorageRequest.get({"id": $rootScope.selectedData, 
    "queriString": query}, function (data){
        key = ??
        $rootScope.values[key] = data[key];
    });
```

Value of `data`:

```
Resource {ABC_12345: Array[3], $get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function…}
```

Response from the server:

```
{
  - ABC_12345: [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

Comment: What method are you calling on the resource object?

Comment: I call get method and get something like `Resource {ABC_12345: Array[3], $get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function…}`

Comment: If we're going to have a chance here, please update your question to include code snippets and, even better, put a sample together on jsFiddle.

Comment: Tnx, I've updated question. I can't provide you sample on jsFiddle, because server for requests is not public jet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually working too hard :).

The *get* method will return a reference to an empty object that will be populated once the asynchronous http call to the resource completes.

You're modelling doesn't make a lot of sense to me though.  Each value should be keyed to it's unique ID - presumably that's what your *selectedData* is.  With that approach, you already know what the 'key' value should be.

It would look something like this:

```
query = "ABC_12345";
$rootScope.values[$rootScope.selectedData] = StorageRequest.get({"id": $rootScope.selectedData, 
"queriString": query}, function (){        
});
```

Comment: Thanks, my key is in `query`, so it should be `$rootScope.values[query] = ...`, but it works. Thanks!
Only problem now is that I have to call `$rootScope.values["ABC_12345"]["ABC_12345"]` to get the result. Is there any option to call just `$rootScope.values["ABC_12345"]`

Comment: Maybe you need to look at how the data is returning from the server.  My guess is that you're returning a hash with a single key of "ABC_12345".  If you're calling get for some id, you should return the  value at that key.  Edit your post to include the raw JSON that's coming back from your get request.

Comment: I've added JSON to the question. I know that key is in that response, but I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: If I was requesting a specific resource from the server, I would not expect it to arrive as a dictionary/hash - I would expect it to be a simple JSON object.  In this case, it looks like your resource IS an array.  But it might be better modeled as a property, say called data, on an object.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Yes, it is array, so you can request multiple objects at once. I don't need this feature at the moment, but I will need it in the future.